# NextJS 13: Do not serve stale content for cached route handlers

Tags: caching, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS 13 with a Route Handler (previously API route) that exports

```
export const revalidate = 1
```

to cache its response for one second. This works as expected. The issue is that when the cache expires, and a new request is made, it gets served the stale content while the cache updates in the background. For example, assume the route returns an integer:

- Call the route. It returns `1`, which then gets cached.
- The value changes from `1` to `2`.
- *After one minute*, another call to the route is made. The cache is outdated, so it returns the stale content (`1`) and updates thereafter.
- Another call to the route is made. Now it returns `2`.

I would like to avoid this serving of stale content. In previous versions, I think this would have been achievable with the `Cache-Control` headers, but I believe NextJS 13 does not really handle these anymore. Is there a way to tell NextJS to not serve stale content, but instead update it first and return the new data?